# ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler error when exporting to jar

Tags: java, hibernate, nullpointerexception

I have a Intellij project which works perfectly in the environment, but when I export it to jar and execute it, I obtain the following error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.toClassDescriptor(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:84)
            at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.toClassDescriptor(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:67)
            at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.handleEntry(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:53)
            at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.visitArchive(JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.java:147)
            at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.scan(AbstractScannerImpl.java:47)
            at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.coordinateScan(ScanningCoordinator.java:76)
            at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.prepare(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:98)
            at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:242)
            at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:175)
            at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:76)
            at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:171)
            at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:119)
            at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:61)
            at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:50)
            at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
            at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
            at database.databaseManager.<init>(databaseManager.java:23)
            at Main.<clinit>(Main.java:25)
```

I have seen so many questions about the same exception, but the answers didnt work for me.

These are the dependencies I am using:

[image: deps]

Answer (score 0):

Finally it was solved by updating:
hibernate-core-5.4.11.Final.jar
to
hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar
Sorry for my stupidity